# Does FileSystemWatcher create its own thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, filesystemwatcher

I want this work to be done in a different thread but do i have to create a thread or does it do all the work on different threads?

Like:

```
Thread fileThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    FileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    FileWatcher.Created += OnFileEvent;
    FileWatcher.Deleted += OnFileEvent;
    FileWatcher.Renamed += OnRenameEvent;
    FileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
});

fileThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't have to create a thread. The events will be called on a separate thread automatically.

Comment: ok perfekt, i got another question: Once i stop the watcher, i set enableraisingeevents = false, but when i want to start the watcher again , i dont know if i should just enableraisingevents=true or if i should create a new instance of the filesystemwatcher like the above code, what do you think? Thank you

Comment: @syncis: If you keep the instance, you can just turn it on again.

Comment: Ok my concern was that i dont want it to do any work at some point and if its enableraisingevents = false , i thought it would do all the work but just not raise the events.

Comment: @syncis: If you are concerned about that, then you should create a new object instead. However, just turning off enableraisingevents will not stop it from listening for changes, you should call Dispose when you don't use it any more.

Comment: How would the debugger handle that?

Comment: @Guffa Why do you think that turning off _EnableRaisingEvents_ will not stop it from listening? What I can see [in the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/io/system/io/FileSystemWatcher.cs,e5f51c0ec64db0d4) is that it will.